# php call function as property

Tags: php, laravel

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body'];
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

Why when I call $post->comments() in php tinker; it gives me this :Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
But when I remove the brackets from the comments word like: $post->comments , I get the array?

Comment: The relation is named comment not comments. And when using with brackets it will return a query builder as far as I know with which you can work

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `$post->comments();`, but `$post->comments;`

Also, your function name should be `public function comments()` not `public function comment()`. You have many comment>s< for each post, not many comment.

Comment: my question is why, not what I should!

Comment: $post->comments() calls the function while $post->comment calls the mapped property (collection)

Comment: @NiekvanderMaaden but the function here return something! why it does not return it?

Comment: If it doesnt return anything it means that either your collection is empty or you configured your hasMany in an incorrect manner. `return $this->hasMany('Namespace\To\Model', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');